# How to do a null check inside the findAll() method

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am querying the BD and some parameter's are optional on the request body. I want to know how can I check the nullability of those fields ( I give categoryId as example) and do the `where` query or not.

```
var categoryId = req.body.category_id

const establishments = await establishment.findAll({
            attributes: [
                "id",
                "description",
                "latitude",
                "longitude",
                [sequelize.literal(' (6371 * acos ( '
                    + 'cos( radians(' + latitude + ') ) '
                    + '* cos( radians( latitude ) ) '
                    + '* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' + longitude + ') )'
                    + '+ sin( radians(' + latitude + ') )'
                    + '* sin( radians( latitude ))))'), 'distance']
            ],
            include: [{
                attributes: [],
                model: subcategory, as: 'subcategories',
                required: false,
            }],
            // nullability check here for categoryId HERE if not null do the where if null don't do
            where: {
                '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId
            },
            establishments: ['id'],
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause should be as follows -

```
where: {
  [op.and]: [
    db.sequelize.literal(`\`subcategories\`.\`category_id\` IS NOT NULL`),
    db.sequelize.literal(`\`subcategories\`.\`category_id\`= ${categoryId}`)
  ]
},
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @Soham I think there is a syntax error with the code. can you fix it for me to approve?

Comment: ')' expected and ',' expected at the end

Answer (score 0):

make your `where` condition:

```
where: [{}, 
    sequelize.where(sequelize.col('category_id'), Op.ne, null),
    {'category_id': {
        [Op.ne]: null
    }}]
```

Comment: where do I input the category id here?

Comment: Unknown column '$subcategories.category_id$' in 'where clause'

Comment: @JoséNobre, I have updated my answer according to your suggestion. Please check and approve.